# Problem with catching exceptions from async code in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have following code inside react app (top level file - just to show the problem, i know its not the right place to do api calls and retrieve the data):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

async function run() {
    try {
        return await fetch("https://somenonexistingplace.com"); 
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } 
}

run();

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I run this code, catch obviously caches the exception but says 'e is undefined' - so I cannot access error message that normally lives in e. [See screenshot from debug session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGWTe.png)

When I run such a code outside of React app in a plain script attached to html, [everything works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMBoy.png) and e is an object with correct error message.

The only difference is that first example lives in React app and second one is outside of React.

So my questions is: what happens here and how to fix it?

EDIT: I know I can replace it with promises and .catch(...) but thats not the point - I am interested in why try/catch does not work here as expected.

Comment: can you show the code inside the react component ?

Comment: you should use fetch(...).catch(...)

Comment: yeah i know buy I am more interested in why this happens

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to change the syntaxis from try/catch to fetch().catch()

```
return await fetch("https://somenonexistingplace.com").catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: yeah i know buy I am more interested in why this happens

Answer (score 1):

`try` / `catch` is great but it only works for imperative code.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html),

> Error boundaries preserve the declarative nature of React, and behave as you would expect. For example, even if an error occurs in a componentDidUpdate method caused by a setState somewhere deep in the tree, it will still correctly propagate to the closest error boundary.

Just example,

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Usage,

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <YourComponent />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: error boundaries are about catching errors in child components while rendering them. This code is far from any rendering...

Answer (score 0):

try this-->

```
URL='http://<--some wrong url -->'

async function run() {
        const resp= await fetch(URL);
        console.log(resp)

}
```

If any error appear it should appear in response it self.

Comment: well I am asking why e cannot be accessed, not how to correctly use fetch and play with responses. Its just to illustrate the problem here - fetch could be replaced with any async code and the problem will be the same.

Comment: yeah got it @ravibagul91 given answer for that !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in node while using axios to fetch response from URL:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function run() {
    try {
        return await axios.get("https://somenonexistingplace.com"); 
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } 
}
```

Got the same problem where await was not working properly while using https module.